# Aspnet chart control goes away after close of Modalwindow

Tags: bar-chart

I have a page which has `Usercontrol` , and 2 `divs` (one `ASPnet(bar)chart` and another `grid`). When i click on a particular bar in the chart control,i open a page in a modal window with `Chart` and `Grid`.All works fine. When i tried to close the modal window, the parent page chart goes away but user control and grid remains as is. What would be problem for the chart not showing on close of `Modal window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because, using chart series.postbackvalue , makes the chart to postback. Set the value to a string and assign the string value to the chart series URL, will ensure the chart remains static and does not disappear.